# Does fast will be broken after yellow paper wasp bite

Tags: sawm

If yellow paper wasp bites us and we went to the hospital for injection to stop swelling and pain relief does that broke our sawm(fast)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes but in such unavoidable situation there will be no penalty/kufarah, you can have fast for later day to complete the count.

Comment: Any evidence for your claims? (See [answer])